# Is there a list of Bitcoin malware

Tags: virus

Does anyone keep a track of various Bitcoin-related malware, such as the recent [DevilRobber Trojan](http://blogs.computerworld.com/19187/devilrobber_trojan_hijacks_macs_for_bitcoin_mining_steals_data_spreads_via_pirated_software)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Started a [Wiki page on this topic](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Malware#Mining_malware).

So far I`ve found mentions of 3 different Bitcoin-related malware:

- Infostealer.Coinbit - steals wallet.dat
- DevilRobber Trojan - mines Bitcoins
- BKDR_BTMINE.DDOS - performs DDoS attacks on miners